# Node.js vs Browser: Chaining rejected promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, promise, es6-promise

If I try this on Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) - **Expected result..**

```
Promise.reject(null).then(console.log);
> Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: null}
```

Whereas if I try on Node v7.8.0 - **Potential error?**

```
Promise.reject(null).then(console.log);
> Promise { <pending> }
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? (I'm assuming the former)

I'm having trouble mocking rejected promises through a handle chain as the rejection doesn't carry through the chain :(

Looking at the MDN docs I think I've got the syntax correct: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: What if you run the node example in a file instead of in the console?

Comment: My unit tests are from a file (which is where I first encountered this). Running the debugger or printing via console also shows same behaviour. Why would running from a file change the behaviour? (New to node & curious)

Comment: Because it's not the same environment. But in this case (and probably most cases these days) it didn't matter.

Comment: Why do you not handle rejected `Promise`?

Comment: Rule #1 - the console lies

Comment: Anyone got a good blog post or explanation why? @guest271314 I tried that but it still gives pending, it give pending no matter what. My main confusion is why (to my layman's knowledge) very similar engines give different answers and how I can get node to behave like chrome :)

Comment: Have little experience with `nodejs`. Even at chromium, the pattern at OP would log a `Uncaught (in promise)` error, as the `Promise` rejection is not handled; though that error is not mentioned at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 Yep it sure does. Getting "Uncaught (in promise) null" as well as the in the OP. Is that chrome magically catching the unresolved promise and rejecting it?

Comment: No chromium is not "magically catching the unresolved promise". The `Promise` is fulfilled at `.reject()` call, though the rejection is not handled at second parameter to `.then()` or `.catch()`. Not sure why `nodejs` is logging `"pending"`

Comment: Cool think we're getting somewhere. So following the code from @hackerrdave below (either variant) I get back a resolved promise. Better than nodejs (and actually what I need in for this project, I took out that to simplify the example further). The problem is nodejs v7.8.0 still gives a pending promise. Seems like a bug to me so will raise on the nodejs tracker I guess.

Comment: Note, a rejected `Promise` can return a resolved `Promise` from second parameter of `.then()`. What does `Promise.reject(null).then(function(data){console.log("resolved", data); return data}, function(data){console.log("rejected", data); return data}).then(function(data){console.log("complete", data); ` log at `console` at `nodejs`?

Comment: Yep that's what I actually need for my code, so was expecting that behaviour as that's what the docs say too! Here's what I get from nodejs v7.8.0: `Promise.reject(null).then(console.log, console.log);
<newline> Promise { <pending> }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both outputs are fine. You should be getting something like `Promise {<rejected>: null}` when logging `Promise.reject(null)` in both consoles.
But what when you chain a `.then(console.log)` to it?

- Chrome applies the rule "*`then()` without a rejection handler returns a promise that gets rejected when the original is rejected*", and it does so immediately - it already knows that the result is going to be a rejected promise
- Node applies the rule "*promises are always asynchronous*". It returns a pending promise and creates callbacks to settle it - in this case, given the original is already rejected and no rejection handler was passed, it is immediately scheduled to reject the result promise.

Both implementations are allowed by the [Promises/A+ standard](https://promisesaplus.com/), the first one might be a bit more efficient while the second one is closer to the behaviour described in the EcmaScript specification.
In practice, you won't notice a difference.

Comment: Cool got it, it's only because I'm using the console (and in my test files also introspecting using console logging) that this behaviour holds! Yeah didn't quite realise that promises are essentially un-inspectable a period of the time but this clears it up, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are rejecting your promise, you need to either define an error handler function as the second arg:

```
Promise.reject(null).then(console.log, console.error);
```

Or use a `.catch()`:

```
Promise.reject(null).catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Yep tried that, I still get pending on Node v7.8.0 :/